# Decipher sing-byte XOR encoded file

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, xor

I have a binary file single-byte xor encoded with a single byte, I tried to brute force files and compare the hash of the generated file with original and couldn't find it, I confirmed the original hash with the author.

the code I wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def bin_xor(data, key):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] ^= key
    return data

data = bytearray(open('sample',  'rb').read())
for key in range(0x00,0xff):
    decoded = bin_xor(data, key)
    name = str(key) + '.bin'
    open(name, "wb").write(decoded)
```

it will generate 255 .bin file then I compare the hash of the files and didn't find it.

Comment: I had a co-worker use single-byte xor "encryption" and I immediately saw the xor byte because there was a section of data that was 0x00 so the xor byte was immediately obvious. If you want encryption use real encryption such as AES.

Comment: thank @zaph I'm not looking for real encryption, I was just deciphering a file, but it's all done, It was a typo in the hash I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the stop value of `0xff` in your `range`, you are actually missing `0xff` itself.

Excerpt from [`range`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges):

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the
>   formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.

You should instead use `0x100` as the stop value.

```
for key in range(0x00,0x100):
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did miss 0xff but still the answer is not correct, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, it appeared it was a typo in the hash thanks.